# Double Quotes Problem to show html content

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a problem in Jquery that prevents me from showing html data with the Jquery popover function:

```
<script>

           jQuery( document ).ready( function(){

                jQuery( '#section' ).popover({
                    content       : '<?php echo $banner;  ?>',
                    interface     : 'popover',
                    position      : 'bottom-left',
                    trigger       : 'click',
                    trigger_off   : 'click',
                              theme           : 'uap-banners-section',
                              title             : 'title',
                })
            })
  </script>
```

Where $Banner is :

```
 $banner = json_encode($data['bannerSection']);
```

The data is being sent fine, but the output has a double quote at the start and at the end of the output data :

```
"<div class="banner_wrapp"><a href="https://misite.com/?ref=103" target="_blank">
<img src="https://mitite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/home-imagen-1.jpg" alt="Inicio" class="imagebar"/></a></div>"
```

That's why the HTML doesn´t show: I guess it's because of the double quotation mark at the beginning and end of the code.

I tried this so far without success:

```
$banner = json_encode(($data['bannerSection']), JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)
$banner = stripslashes($data['bannerSection']);
$banner = stripslashes(json_encode($data['bannerSection']));
```

How I can remove this quotation mark in my code?

Comment: As a really bad fix you could use php trim() and select the double quotes as the character to trim. That will remove the double quotes from the start and end.

Comment: Why are you using json_encode() when it appears you are injecting $banner directly into the JS.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON representation for a string is enclosed in quotes. However, if you do:

```
$banner = json_encode($data['bannerSection']);
echo $banner;
```

The output will be:

```
<div class="banner_wrapp"><a href="https://misite.com/?ref=103" target="_blank"> <img src="https://mitite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/home-imagen-1.jpg" alt="Inicio" class="imagebar"/></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `'` or `"` quotes in JS is totally up to you so you don't need the single quotes in the `popover()` call, simply remove it:

```
jQuery( '#section' ).popover({
    content       : <?php print json_encode($data['bannerSection']); ?>,
    interface     : 'popover',
    position      : 'bottom-left',
    trigger       : 'click',
    trigger_off   : 'click',
    theme         : 'uap-banners-section',
    title         : 'title',
});
```

This might look wrong but as the PHP code will be evaluated on page render time it will be switched with the banner content before being sent to the client.

As already mentioned in the comments, it seems the `json_encode()` is totally unnecessary and will only wrap the string in extra quotes plus escape special characters like double-quotes. Therefor this should also work:

```
jQuery( '#section' ).popover({
    content       : '<?php print $data['bannerSection']; ?>',
    interface     : 'popover',
    position      : 'bottom-left',
    trigger       : 'click',
    trigger_off   : 'click',
    theme         : 'uap-banners-section',
    title         : 'title',
});
```